# How to integrate stream's signup/login into a react native application?

Tags: react-native, getstream-io

I'm trying to integrate stream into my react native application. I've successfully done the integration of `FlatFeed` and stream's chat. I want to know whether I can use stream's login and signup in my application. Does stream provide the support for that?

I found this doc explaining about getting token https://getstream.io/blog/tutorial-user-auth-with-stream-chat-feeds/ . But from where do we get the endpoints for login and signup.How does this works? I can't find any other docs explaining this. So please reply.

Comment: Not supported, you need a backend of yourself to generate your tokens.

Answer (score 1):

Not supported.

Users of stream need their own backend to generate user tokens, even if this is a simple lambda function.

> I added into a comment but since the question is a yes/no question, writing it as an answer too.